# Chart requirement for an application

Tags: charts, gantt-chart

Am working on an application that has a requirement like, All the tasks has to be represented in a gantt view with milestones and critical path. Chart should also show the analysis of Baseline vs Actual and % of complete of the task. Also i should be able to specify colors for each type of tasks. Any suggestions on the charts that i should be using? I tried Google Charts, it is not meeting the requirement. Also tried Kendo UI, am getting the Gantt chart and % complete. But baseline vs Actual is not present in the same chart. Kindly point me to a correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Akshar,

What you need is the [RadiantQ jQuery Gantt Package](http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/). You can see all your requirements illustrated in our [online sample](http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm). Take a look at the "Project Gantt" and "Common" samples on the left.

- In all our samples, task progress is illustrated.
- In any
  sample, change the End-Time to be the same as the Start-Time and you
  will see it turn into a **milestone**.
- The very 2nd sample
  **GanttControlCriticalPath** illustrates built in critical path support.
- **Baselines** are illustrated in the
  GanttControlTemplateSample (11th one in the list).
- GanttControlCustomAppearance illustrates how to bind the color of a
  task to a property in the task.

Good luck with your project!